# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable? What does it mean?

Tags: python, list, text-files

```
ClassNames = studentname and score
if studentname not in ClassNames:
   ClassNames = ClassNames.append(studentname)
for studentname in filename and ClassNames <= 3:
    FirstResult.append(score)
    SecondResult.append|(score)
    ThirdResult.append(score)
```

The `if` line gives me the error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: `ClassNames = studentname and score` - what do you expect that to do?

Comment: Can you specify an example of content you use for 'studentname' and 'score'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClassNames = studentname and score
```

most likely sets the variable `ClassNames` to `score` which sounds like it could by of `int`.

By calling

```
if studentname not in ClassNames:
    ...
```

you iterate through `ClassNames` to find `studentname`, but like your error says, `int` is not iterable.

Further problems:

1. `list.append()` works inplace and returns `None`
2. `ClassNames <= 3` makes only sense, if it is an `int`

Comment: Thank you! and if ClassNames <= 3 only makes sense if it is an int, what can I use instead?

Comment: You might want to have a look into [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Answer (score -1):

Your `ClassName` is result of boolean operation *and*, so it can take value either True or False (0 or 1). Because it is non-iterable type, you are getting this error.

Re-think what data you want to keep in your `ClassName`.

Comment: That's not correct in [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).